# PHP and MySQL, How to select fields in "Sparse" Table, avoiding nulls

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I have one table with hundreds of columns, but almost all are null.

Each 'select' in this table return only one line, with hundreds of fields.

Working with PHP, I am testing each field with:

```
if (!empty($dataset["field"])) { ... }
```

For optimization reasons, If I select only the valued fields I can use array functions to know the name of each field, and speed up my application.

But how can I select only the fields with values in this case, with MySQL 5.6 ?

something like:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ONLY fields_not_null();
```

This table records the amount of events per minute during one day. The recordset is basically:

1. one field for date
2. 60x24 fields for minutes in the day (1440 fields)

Change it to 24 tables (for each hour) decrease the performance, and we still have dozens of null fields in each table.

Change it to one recordset with date_time and boolean is the worst scenario for performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `col IS NOT NULL`: `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE column IS NOT NULL`

Comment: From the looks of it: "Each 'select' in this table return only one line, with hundreds of fields. ".  He doesn't want to exclude rows where a column is null, he wants to get rid of the null columns from the row in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

To me, this is an indication that your MySQL database is not properly constructed.

The easiest way to do this in PHP would be to use **[array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)**.

For example: `array_filter($row)` would get rid of all the empty values (loosely equivalent to false).  If you only wanted to get rid of null and empty values but leave 0's then you can use a different callback, for example **strlen** which would return only values that have at least one character:

```
$filteredRow = array_filter($row, 'strlen');
```

Now **$filteredRow** will have all the fields that have values in a field=>value array.  If you just want the field names, you can use [**array_keys**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php):

```
$fields = array_keys($filteredRows);
```

Comment: I need to save the amount of events ocurred by minute during the day. The database was constructed correct.  The concept of "Sparse Matrix" is real.

Comment: I doubt the database is properly normalized if you are having to do this.

Comment: @RicardodeMagalhãesSimões Just because you're doing a Sparse Matrix doesn't mean it is going to be optimal for MySQL.  MySQL isn't a graphing/mathematical database.   If the database isn't normalized, these are the problems you are going to run into.  I'd need more details on your sparse matrix to guide you further if my solution can't be used.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what you will be doing with the data, I can't point at a single solution.  Here are several:

Plan A:  Let the application code deal with all the NULLs.

Plan B:  Have one row per non-NULL minute.  You may want to use the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function.

Plan C:  Use `COALESCE()` and/or `IFNULL()` functions.

Plan D:  Store the non-NULL values in an associative array (minute->value), serialize into a JSON string, store the JSON ins a `TEXT` field.

Do not use 24 tables.

Do not try to have 1440 columns in a table; it will not work in InnoDB.